# How do I read an unknown file type?

Tags: algorithm, file-type

I have a file. It's not a text file. What is the logical process and tests one would use to read the file to see what it contains? File structure, vendor, data are all unknown.

Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

Comment: It's a 7zip file, so there you go, structure is known.

Comment: @harold: I would say it's _almost certainly_ a 7zip file :)

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to check against the list of known file signatures also known as magic numbers. Check `file` utility on GNU/Linux.

[List of file signatures from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Answer (score 2):

In Linux you can use the `file` command to determine the type of a given file. `file` determines the type of file using a pattern that is taken from a special pattern file named `magic`. To determine, it parses the content of the "unknown" file. For more detailed information consult the man page of the [`file(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command and the [`magic(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) pattern file.

```
$ echo "Hello World" > foo.txt 
$ mv foo.txt foo
$ file foo
foo: ASCII text

$ echo '#!/bin/bash' > foo 
$ file foo 
foo: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable

$ zip foo.zip foo
updating: foo (stored 0%)
$ mv foo.zip foo
$ file foo
foo: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```